# How to add rows in a table made using datagrid view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have some data that is present in some textboxes (say 10) on a winform. Now what i want is to display a summary of all the information in the textboxes in a table.
I have tried using datagrid view but i don't know how do you add rows to it.
i have looked at various answer but none of them seem to solve my problem.
table format is something like this:

```
TYPE             DESCRIPTION 
row1 
row2
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you cannot add rows in datagridview databound ..

Comment: then can you please suggest something to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are manually entering data into DataGridView, you can get all texts from the TextBoxes and do below.

First add columns

```
        DataGridView.Columns.Add(columnName, headerText);
```

Then create row for each set of data.

```
        var newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
        newRow.CreateCells(DataGridView);
        newRow.SetValues(valueArrayForRow);
        DataGridView.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with properties represents the fields that you have in the form.

Assume you have created class `Student`.

1. Create List students = new List();
2. Now if you want to display the values in the textbox in the
   datagridview, First populate the student object with the values.(Set
   the values to respective property using TextBox values)
3. Add the populated Student object to the created `Students` list.
   `students.Add(studentObject)`;
4. Set the `Students` list as the data source for the DataGridView.
   `dataGridView1.DataSource = student;`

**EDIT**

If you want to add empty row or new row to the datagrid view, Update the bound `Students` list and then `reset the datasource`.

```
//Assume Student list is bound as Dtaasource
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

//Add a new student object to the list
students .Add(new Student());

//Reset the Datasource
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = students;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//create datatable and columns,
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column 1"));
dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column 2"));

//simple way create object for rowvalues here i have given only 2 add as per you requirement
object[] RowValues = { "", "" };

//assign values into row object
RowValues[0] = "your value 1";
RowValues[1] = "your value 2";

//create new data row
DataRow dRow;
dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues);
dtable.AcceptChanges();

//now bind datatable to gridview... 
grv.datasource=dbtable;
grv.databind();
```